# Render Animation with layers

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine, layers, world

I'm trying to render an animation using version 2.90.1, but my PC has no chance rendering it all at once, cant even get past the first frame without vram used up.

I tried doing it with layers and I managed to render an image without it failing, but I'm wondering how I can render it as an animation/video file, as I cant find the FFmpeg in the file output settings.

Also I'm using dynamic sky for lighting and clouds etc, but can find a way to put the dynamic sky world settings into a layer/collection for it to render. And if so, does the lighting from the world settings affect the other layers?

Comment: Try compositing, maybe?

Comment: It is not recommended to render a video file (FFmpeg) directly, because if Blender crashes, you have a damaged file and have to start over. It is better to output single frames (png (lossless) or jpeg (loss of detail, but smaller file size) as animation and then use Blender's video workspace to create the video from the frames. If it crashes, it can continue where it crashed.

Comment: Render each frame and layer separately as an image sequence in EXR format.  Then composite them together in the compositor. Once you render those frames then encode as video.